# select only numeric values otherwise return NULL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, where-clause

I am quite new to Oracle.

I have a column in Oracle called `Salary` that has values like `'19000.00'`, `NULL`, `N/A`, prefer not to say, `'17500'`.

How do I write a sql query that returns numerical values = no letters or null?

From the example above would be `'19000.00'`, `'17500.00'`. Otherwise for all non-numeric values, including `NULL` and letters, returns `NULL`. For example for `NULL`, `N/A`, prefer not to say.

```
select salary from myTable where ...?
```

Comment: don't store numbers in `varchar` columns

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a regex to filter the table, like: `REGEXP_LIKE(salary, '\d+(\.\d+)?')`

This expression allows a sequence of digits, optionnaly followed by a dot and more digits.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19811c4c8ec3ad68153c7019c93a4d0a)**:

```
with x as (
    SELECT 'N/A' salary FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT NULL FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT '19000.00' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT '17500' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(salary, '\d+(\.\d+)?')
```

Yields:

```
| SALARY   |
| :------- |
| 19000.00 |
| 17500    |
```

---

PS: if don't want to filter out the non-numeric values but replace them with `NULL` instead, then:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(salary, '\d+(\.\d+)?') THEN salary END FROM x
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12.2 you can use `VALIDATE_CONVERSION`:

```
select salary
from my_table
where VALIDATE_CONVERSION(salary AS NUMBER) = 1;
```

Or to show NULLs for the non-numbers:

```
select case when VALIDATE_CONVERSION(salary AS NUMBER) = 1 then salary end 
from my_table;
```